# How to get connected linestring from postgres table using postgis?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table with id, geometry where geometry is of type linestring or multilinestring.
I want to group all the linestrings which are connected to each other. For e.g.

```
Id  geometry
 1  linestring(a, b)
 2  linestring(b, c)
 3  linestring(b, d)
 4  linestring(e, f)
```

then the result should be

```
Id       geometry
1,2,3   linestring(a,b,c,d)
4       linestring(e, f)
```

I tried doing `st_intersects` and `st_union` which gives multilinestring with one row only.

```
select STRING_AGG(t.id::TEXT, ', '), st_union(t.geom) from table t
group by ST_intersects(t.geom, t.geom)
```

Comment: You can conver it to multilinestring https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294885/convert-linestring-to-multilinestring-in-postgis

Comment: You can cluster the data with a distance of 0, as done [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451111/dissolve-union-large-number-1-2m-polygons-in-postgis)

Comment: PS: `group by ST_intersects(t.geom, t.geom)` is the same as `group by TRUE` or as no group by at all, so your query is effectively aggregating all rows

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love them recursive CTEs

```
WITH RECURSIVE some_points AS (
    SELECT
        ST_MakePoint(0, 0) AS a,
        ST_MakePoint(1, 0) AS b,
        ST_MakePoint(2, 0) AS c,
        ST_MakePoint(1, 1) AS d,
        ST_MakePoint(0, 2) AS e,
        ST_MakePoint(1, 2) AS f
), some_lines AS (
    SELECT
        UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3,4]) AS id,
        UNNEST(ARRAY[
            ST_MakeLine(a, b),
            ST_MakeLine(b, c),
            ST_MakeLine(b, d),
            ST_MakeLine(e, f)
        ]) AS geom
    FROM some_points
), paths AS ( -- for each line segment add connected line segments recursively
        SELECT id AS path_id, 1 AS degree, ARRAY[id] AS ids, geom
        FROM some_lines
    UNION ALL
        SELECT p.path_id, degree + 1, ARRAY_APPEND(p.ids, l.id), ST_Union(p.geom, l.geom)
        FROM paths AS p
            INNER JOIN some_lines AS l
                ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom)
                AND NOT ST_Contains(p.geom, l.geom)
), paths_expanded AS ( -- expand paths so we can order them
    SELECT
        array_to_string(ids, ',') AS path_variation_id,
        geom,
        degree,
        MAX(degree) OVER(PARTITION BY path_id) AS max_degree,
        UNNEST(ids) AS id
    FROM paths
), full_paths_ordered AS ( -- order full paths so we can remove duplicates
    SELECT path_variation_id, geom, ARRAY_AGG(id ORDER BY id) AS ids
    FROM paths_expanded
    WHERE degree = max_degree
    GROUP BY path_variation_id, geom
) -- remove duplicate paths
SELECT DISTINCT ON(ids) ids, ST_AsText(geom) AS wkt
FROM full_paths_ordered
ORDER BY ids, path_variation_id;
```

Returns:

| ids | wkt |
| --- | --- |
| {1,2,3} | MULTILINESTRING((0 0,1 0),(1 0,2 0),(1 0,1 1)) |
| {4} | LINESTRING(0 2,1 2) |